# "No changes detected in your mapping information" when adding Gedmo Timestampable trait

Tags: php, doctrine, database-migration

I have added a trait to my existing SentNewsletter class. So it now looks like this:

```
...

use Gedmo\Timestampable\Traits\Timestampable;

/**
 * SentNewsletter
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="sent_newsletter")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\SentNewsletterRepository")
 */
class SentNewsletter
{
    use Timestampable;

...
```

But when I run `bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff` I get

> No changes detected in your mapping information.

I have tried running `bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata`, and this does not fix the situation. Does anyone have any ideas about what I might need to do in order to generate a valid migration?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that I needed to use `TimestampableEntity` rather than `TimeStampable`. The former has annotations that the latter lacks.

Without those annotations, doctrine had been unable to generate a diff.

Problem solved.